# Android Facebook Login API returns only name and id

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Hi i am using Facebook graph Api in android application, i am able to submit a request and get response but although my scope is `"email", "user_birthday",  "public_profile"` it returns only name and id.

```
private void onFblogin()  {
        callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // Set permissions
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList( "email", "user_birthday",  "public_profile"));

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                        System.out.println("Success");
                        GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                                            // handle error
                                            System.out.println("ERROR");
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("Success");
                                            try {

                                                String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                                                System.out.println("JSON Result"+jsonresult);

                                                String name = json.getString("name");
                                                String str_email = json.getString("email");
                                                String str_id = json.getString("id");


                                                //boolean loggedIn = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null;
                                                //get profile data
                                              //  LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
                                                String str_firstname = json.getString("first_name");
                                                String str_lastname = json.getString("last_name");

                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                }).executeAsync();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("facebook Login","On cancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Log.d("facebook Login",error.toString());
                    }
                });
    }


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        } else if(requestCode == FB_SIGN_IN){
            callbackmanager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

**Gradle**

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
```

[image]

can someone help me to get all the information in public_profile

Comment: i believe there are other api calls to get all of that users information. when working with login api, its strickly login info. look at the graph api. you can get everything from that.

Comment: please refere https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not specify any fields, check out the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

For example:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                   JSONObject object,
                   GraphResponse response) {
                // Application code
            }
        });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,birthday");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Without specifying the fields parameter, you will only get a few default fields in the response. That´s for all API calls.

Check out "Choosing fields" in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api